# Trying to read DBM file

Tags: python, c, linux, perl, dbm

I have a stripped down real-time Linux box that interfaces with some hardware.

The configuration files are *.dbm files and I cannot access them. They seem to be some sort of key-value database but every library I have tried has come up empty.

I have tried the DBM reading libraries from Perl, Python, and Ruby with no luck. Any guidance on these files would be great, I have not seen them before.

This is what happens when I cat one file out.

```
 DBMFILE  Aug 31 2004,�
,jy                    �
�~���"��+�K&��gB��7JJ�
                                         ,��GLOBA.PB_COMBI�SMSI���
JG]
,��BUS_DP
PC  �
            '

xLokalT
          J��
                ,��SL_DP
                             PC!�
                                    ��
#,��PLC_PARAMJPf,��PROJEKT�PROFIBUS new network1.00022.02.2012J,��KBL_HEADER:�JJp,��KBLJ��,��ALI-SETUPB ����
������������������JJ,,��OBJ-DEFJJ��,��ALI_CLIENTTJJ�
,��ALI_SERVERJ      J\r�����2,  ��      ST_OV_00Boolean0Integer8    0Integer16
0Integer32
            0Unsigned8
0Unsigned32Floating-Point0igned16
Octet String Jo� ,��DESCRIPT �ABB OyABB Drives RPBA-01ABBSlave1***reserved***�
                                                                                      �
                                                                                      %
```

So to show what i've tried already, and only come up with empty objects ( no key-values)*edit

perl -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

use strict;

use DB_File;
use GDBM_File;

my ($filename, %hash, $flags, $mode, $DB_HASH) = @ARGV;

tie %hash,  'DB_File', [$filename, $flags, $mode, $DB_HASH]
  or die "Cannot open $filename: $!\n";

while ( my($key, $value) = each %hash ) {
   print "$key = $value\n";
}

 # these unties happen automatically at program exit                                                                                                                                                                                            
untie %hash;
```

which returns nothing

python -

```
db = dbm.open('file', 'c')
```

ruby -

```
db = DBM.open('file', 666, DBM::CREATRW)
```

Every one of these returned empty. I assume they use the same low level library. Some history/context on DBM files would be great as there seems to be some different versions.

**Edit

running file on it returns

```
$ file abb12mb_uncontrolledsynch_ppo2_1slave.dbm 
abb12mb_uncontrolledsynch_ppo2_1slave.dbm: data
```

and running strings outputs

```
$ strings abb12mb_uncontrolledsynch_ppo2_1slave.dbm 
DBMFILE  
Aug 31 2004
GLOBAL
PB_COMBI
SMSI
BUS_DP
Lokal
SL_DP
PLC_PARAM
PROJEKT
PROFIBUS new network
1 .000
22.02.2012
KBL_HEADER
ALI-SETUP
OBJ-DEF
ALI_CLIENT
ALI_SERVER
ST_OV_0
Boolean
Integer8
Integer16
Integer32
Unsigned8
Unsigned16
Unsigned32
Floating-Point
Octet String
DESCRIPT
ABB Oy
ABB Drives RPBA-01
ABBSlave1
***reserved***
```

Comment: have you tried `file $filename` of `strings $filename`?

Comment: The answer is to use a DBM library, such as Perl's [`DB_File`](https://metacpan.org/module/DB_File). *"I have tried the DBM reading libraries from perl, python, ... with no luck."* Please show what you have written and describe how it isn't working for you.

Comment: Ran `file` and `Strings` no information or values retrieved. updated post to show different attempts

Comment: It is very odd to assign your complete list of variables from `@ARGV`. For one thing, `%hash` will take all of the parameters after the first, and the remainder will all be set to `undef`. I suggest you use the default parameters and write just `my $filename = shift; tie my %hash, 'DB_File', $filename;`

Answer (score 1):

Just to make my comment clear, you should try using the default options for [`DB_File`](https://metacpan.org/module/DB_File), like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DB_File;

my ($filename) = @ARGV;

tie my %dbm, 'DB_File', $filename or die qq{Cannot open DBM file "$filename": $!};

print "$_\n" for keys %dbm;
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I tried that code with this result  

`$ perl dbr.pl abb12mb_uncontrolledsynch_ppo2_1slave.dbm`

 
`Cannot open DBM file "abb12mb_uncontrolledsynch_ppo2_1slave.dbm":  at dbr.pl line 9.`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for Perl's dbmopen function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dbmopen.html):

> [This function has been largely superseded by the tie function.]

You probably want to try `tie`ing it with [DB_File](http://perldoc.perl.org/DB_File.html).

```
 use DB_File;
 tie %hash,  'DB_File', $filename, $flags, $mode, $DB_HASH;
```

Then your data is in `%hash`.

Might also be interesting to run `file` against the file to see what it actually is.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I tried it and it opened the file but did not print anything. I edited the post to show my code

Comment: What does `file` say?

Comment: Note that the square brackets in the documentation indicate optional sections of the syntax. Using them in this context is misleading as it implies that you should be passing an anonymous array.